# when does a Leadbolt notification ad show?

Tags: android, leadbolt

I have implemented the notification ads per the "How-to" guide:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and

```
String leadboltNoticationId = Application.getInstance().getLeadboltNoticationId();
AdController myController = new AdController(getApplicationContext(),
            leadboltNoticationId);
myController.setAsynchTask(true);
myController.loadNotification();
```

no ads show in the notification bar.  Nothing shows in the logs. "leadboltNoticationId" is filled correctly with the id.  How long do i need to wait for an ad to show up?  Is there a way to force an ad to show up immediately?  I don't have access to the docs so please dont reference them unless you are going to give me a publicly accessible download link.

Answer (score 0):

You can force to show the notification by setting the notification in your Leadbot-Accout to recurring.